# Rails4 how to create the model relationship on join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is *user* table:

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :password
  t.string  :department

  t.timestamps
end
```

this is *meet* table:

```
create_table :meets do |t|
  t.string :name, null: false
  t.string :state, null: false
  t.string :description, null: false
  t.string :location, null: false
  t.float  :spend, null: false
  t.timestamps
end
```

The following is a relationship between user and meet:

1. user can create many meets
2. a meet can have many participants(users)

I am new to study rails, i tried to create migration and model, But i do not know the correct way:

1. *User can create many meets*, I think i can add reference in **meets** migrate to create a one to one relationship

   ```
   t.references :users
   ```
2. *a meet can have many users*, I think i must create a join table:

   ```
   rails g migration CreateJoinTableUsersMeets user meet
   ```

The above command will auto generate a migration file:

```
create_join_table :Users, :Ploys do |t|
  t.index [:user_id, :ploy_id]
  t.index [:ploy_id, :user_id]
end
```

But i want know how to create model relationship on join tabel?

Comment: What do you mean by 'how to create the model relationship on join table'? Are you trying to create associations? What do you mean by 'relationship'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```
create_table :users do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.string :password
    t.string :department

    t.timestamps
end

create_table :meets do |t|
    t.string :name, null: false
    t.string :state, null: false
    t.string :description, null: false
    t.string :location, null: false
    t.float :spend, null: false
    t.references :creator, class_name: "User"

    t.timestamps
end

create_table :participations do |t|
    t.references :user
    t.references :meet
end

add_index :participations, [:user_id, :meet_id]
add_index :participations, [:meet_id, :user_id]



class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :meets, through: :participations
    has_many :created_meets, class_name: "Meet", foreign_key: "creator_id"
end

class Meet < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, through: :participations
    belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"
end
```

You do not create a one to one relationship in the table but you just have to create a join table called participations. That model will have a reference to a user and a meet. Then, you can specify has_and_belongs_to_many by adding the above code to both models. The point is that it uses the join table to create associations. Comment if you have any other question :)

Comment: But how could i know that which user create a meet?

Comment: That is a good point and you could definitely create a separate column. I will edit the answer for that. You create a separate column called creator_id by t.references :creator, class_name: "User", then write out the association by the following line: belongs_to :creator, class_name: "User"

Comment: Thank you,i love your answer so much!

Comment: I'm sorry, i read your code again, but i don't know what the meaning of "Group"

Comment: Does this make sense to you? the association meets indicate meets a user is participating in, and the created_meets indicate meets that a user has created.

Comment: But i think **t.belongs_to** better than **t.references** in migration, because don't need add **foreign_key** in model,